# How to correctly specify the copy constructor

Tags: c++

Assume I have a class Matrix, with a constructor as follows:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    nrows = a; //here nrows is the number of rows for each matrix 
    ncols = b; //here ncols is the number of cols for each matrix
    p = new double [rows*cols];
    for(int i=0;i<rows*cols;i++) 
        { 
            *p++ = 0.0;
        }
}
```

Suppose I also have a 'copy' constructor as follows:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& mat)
{   p = new double[mat.nrows*mat.ncols];
    for(int i=0;i<mat.nrows*mat.ncols;i++)
        { 
             p[i] = mat.p[i];

        }
}
```

Now also suppose I have the following lines in my main function:

```
int main()
    {
        Matrix A(2,2);
        Matrix B(2,2);
        A = Matrix(B); //call overloaded assignment operator, and copy ctor/
     }
```

Here the '=' operator is overloaded to assign all the elements in B to A.
My issue is that once the call to the copy constructor is made, the Matrix A object is a completely new object.

Is there a better way of writing the copy constructor so that if Matrix A already exists then calling A = Matrix(B) results in an error?

Comment: Why do you wan't to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Matrix A object is a completely new object"?

Comment: You can't assign to an object that doesn't already exist. If you want to disallow assignment, ask about that. (Remember that `Matrix A = B;` isn't assignment but initialisation.)

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess I was wondering in general, if there was something I should be doing in order to prevent this happening. What I have presented above is an example, but was curious if in general I should be coding in a way that prevents this type of issue....

Comment: @Pradhan amended. Thanks.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes you are right. I have amended the code I was missing a statement here.

Comment: `p = new double[mat.nrows * ncols]` should be `p = new double[mat.nrows * mat.ncols]`. (i.e. you forgot a `mat.`)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Thanks...amended this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using dynamically allocated arrays, I would recommend using `std::vector`

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(long rows, long cols);
private:
    long nrows;
    long ncols;
    std::vector<double> p;
}
```

Then your constructor can be

```
Matrix::Matrix(long rows, long cols)
: nrows(rows),
  ncols(cols),
  p(rows * cols)
{ }
```

Along with [all of the other benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) of using `std::vector` over dynamically allocated arrays, you now get a compiler-generated copy constructor, so you don't need to write one.

If you don't want your class to be copyable, `delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(long rows, long cols);
    Matrix(const Matrix& mat) = delete;
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& mat) = delete;
private:
    long nrows;
    long ncols;
    std::vector<double> p;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the statement

```
A = Matrix(B);
```

first a *temporary object* is create using the copy-constructor. This temporary object is then used in the assignment.

So it's true that the copy-constructor is used, but not as part of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

It would be *far* better to *delete* the assignment operator:

`Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&) = delete;`

Then use of `A = Matrix(B)` would emit a compile time error. You'd then be forced to use the constructor and your specific issue would cease to be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for this...not entirely sure though how the '=delete' works. Does this mean that any special member function/operator defined this way, cannot be called? so in effect we don't have a assignment operator (including default assignment operator) and thus we use the copy constructor for assignments as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Google "C++ member deletion".

Answer (score 0):

No. Because then it wouldn't be a copy *constructor*. A constructor constructs.